# Jquery button toggle change text and span class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a working toggle button that slides a div up and down. The problem I have is when I try changing the toggle button status:

A demo of my code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/zwu0sn83/3/

Button code, with inner span for the icon:

```
<a href="#" id="toggle-reveal" class="c-1 sort-btn" title="Filter Products"><span class="ico sort"></span> Filter Products</a>
```

I'm using the following to change text but the span html is actul text rather than html. I need to change text and update the span class:

```
$(this).text(function(i, text){
      return text === "<span class='ico sort'></span>Filter Products" ? "<span class='ico close-sort'></span>Close Filters" : "<span class='ico sort'></span>Filter Products";
});
```

Comment: So `.html()` instead of `.text()` no? I don't understand what you mean by _"but the span html is actul text rather than html. I need to change text and update the span class"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `$(this).text()`, use `$(this).html()`.

What you are inserting ... `<span class='ico sort'></span>Filter Products" ? "<span class='ico close-sort'></span>Close Filters" : "<span class='ico sort'></span>Filter Products` ... has html code, not just text.

Answer (score 0):

what you are changing is text but you are comparing html try; for example `$(this).text()` returns "Filter Products" but `.html()` returns "`<span class="ico sort"></span> Filter Products`"

you can use html instead with the same logic;

```
$(this).html(function(i, oldHTML){
      //alternatively you can use oldHTML.indexOf("Products") > -1
      return oldHTML === "<span class='ico sort'></span>Filter Products" ? "<span class='ico close-sort'></span>Close Filters" : "<span class='ico sort'></span>Filter Products";
});
```

but this cases I am using a class toggle which in your case also require some html structure changes.

```
$(this).toggleClass("filter")
```

and with a simple css you can switch the view e.g.

```
a.filter span.sort {
   display:hidden;
}
```

separation of html and js is always a good practice.